# Animate a div's height and have the divs below move down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I want to have columns of divs and when the user clicks on a div he/she can see more in the div because the height gets bigger. I set that up but it looks like I have a document flow problem. when I click on the div in the first column the divs underneath it does something funny. The one below goes to the next column like half way. That's not good I want it to just  move down in the first columns and and have the other, lower divs follow. This actually happens in the second column. that's good but the problem is that when I click on the divs in the second column the first column makes the same space. The first column should do nothing. How would you fix this problem?

one way I was thinking was to have 2 columns floating left instead of each div and I think that will fix the document flow problem. but that would mess up the convenience of the floating left for the divs because the **divs need to be in order.**

```js
$(function(){
  $(".box").on("click", function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")){
      $(this).addClass("open");
      $(this).animate({
        height : "+=100"
      })
    }else{
      $(this).animate({
        height : "-=100"
      })
      $(this).removeClass("open")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html{
  font-size: 18;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 40em;
  height: 60em;
  background: #ccc;
}
.box{
  float: left;
  height: 8em;
  width: 18em;
  background: tomato;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.box:nth-child(even){
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Below is the effect that I want. It's not so good because now I'm going to have to do operations when I want to insert the div's data dynamically I don't know. 1 and 2 are supposed to be next to each other. It shows that on the screen but there separated far in the html. this might cause confusion later. If someone has a better way let me know.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".box").on("click", function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")){
      $(this).addClass("open")
      $(this).animate({
        height : "+=100"
      })
    }else{
      $(this).animate({
        height : "-=100"
      })
      $(this).removeClass("open")
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
.wrapper{
  width: 40em;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 40em;
}
.col1{
  float: left;
  width: 19em;
}
.col2{
  float: right;
  width: 19em;
}
.box{
  background: tomato;
  height: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex`, remove `float` and the quirky misalignment is gone.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".box").on("click", function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")){
      $(this).addClass("open");
      $(this).animate({
        height : "+=100"
      })
    }else{
      $(this).animate({
        height : "-=100"
      })
      $(this).removeClass("open")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html{
  font-size: 18;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40em;
  background: #ccc;
}
.box{
  height: 8em;
  width: 18em;
  background: tomato;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.box:nth-child(even){
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

To make them not push either side down (row by row) and create that white space gap, you can either use columns (see sample below) or you will need something like the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

```js
$(function(){
  $(".box").on("click", function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")){
      $(this).addClass("open");
      $(this).animate({
        height : "+=100"
      })
    }else{
      $(this).animate({
        height : "-=100"
      })
      $(this).removeClass("open")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html{
  font-size: 18;
}
.wrapper{
  -webkit-columns: 18em 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 18em 2; /* Firefox */
  columns: 18em 2;
  background: #ccc;
}
.box{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8em;
  width: 18em;
  background: tomato;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  order: 1;
}
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you for your answer. I like the second one better (`columns:`)  but there are issues. first of all when you view it in full screen it is messed up. so I put a `width: 40em;  height: 60em;` on the `.wrapper` and it looked better. but if i click on 4 and 6 the col get messed up. and there's reorder of the html.  the first one is ok. but the other column moves down and I can't get  masonry to work http://codepen.io/JackSchuldenfrei/pen/YwBdqm  I put a click event to change the height on `.grid-item` but the ones below didn't move. so this is still a prob.

Comment: @jackblank - I personally think there are two good solutions offered here,  You cant really expect someone to type up a complete working example that you just copy and paste right into your project